# find: show directories which contain certain subdirectories

Tags: linux, find, gnu

I have a list of directories

```
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/devel
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_flink
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/totalstable
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/develbi
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tgn
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tdhmdcuat
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_tdhmdc
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_tdh
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/grow
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/sgsb
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tdhmdc
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_grow
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/masupport
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/totalslow
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_sgsb
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tdh
```

But only a subset of these contain */out directory:

```
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/devel/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_flink/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_grow/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_sgsb/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_tdhmdc/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_tdh/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tdhmdc/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/tdh/out
```

I wondered if there was a way to use a command (such as `find`) which, given `/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs`, will return this list:

```
devel
ecom_flink
ecom_grow
ecom_sgsb
ecom_tdhmdc
ecom_tdh
tdhmdc
tdh
```

Without the help of `grep` or `grep`-like filters/tools (`sed`, `awk`, and friends)

Comment: Why no grep etc?

Comment: IMO, `grep` and friends are over utilised, when native functionality exists in existing tools. Take `ls | grep` combinations, for example, which can often substituted with `shopt -s extglob` features of Bash shell.

Comment: isn't that rather fighting the whole philosophy of do one thing and do it well. Rather than rely on a program to do everything, you chain smaller components together to do what you want. My answer below does what you want, but is it any better than using sed?

Answer (score 4):

```
find /u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs -type d -name "out"
```

returns the subset of folders,

```
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/devel/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_flink/out
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_grow/out
…etc
```

you can then run dirname on those results:

```
find /u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs -type d -name "out" -exec dirname {} \;

/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/devel
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_flink
/u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs/ecom_grow
…etc
```

And by using sh -c you can execute basename on that result:

```
find /u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs -type d -name "out" -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "$0")"' {} \;
```

thanks slhck for the above.

The question is: is running a shell containing a process that works on the output of a subshell containing another process simpler, faster or better than piping the output of find to sed/awk?

Comment: For the latter to work you'd need a call to `sh -c` and pass `{}` as an argument.

Comment: amended, thank you. I learnt something today!

Comment: Glad I could help. With this trick you can basically do almost anything through `find` and shell builtins. You *might* need to test this on folders that contain spaces in their name, because I think you need `"basename "$(dirname "$0")"` to be safe.

Comment: ah, yes, good point. I spent ages trying to work out how to quote the results, I didn't know you could nest quotation marks inside a subshell. I thought that it would be interpreted as `"basename $(dirname"` `$0` and `")"`

Answer (score 0):

```
find /u2/tip/coy/inter/fcs -name 'out' -type d |
while read line ; do
    IFS='/'
    set -- $line
    num=$(( $# - 1))
    eval  "echo \"\${$num}\""
done
```

but this will miserably fail when filename have embedded newlines